# Is everything linked to Function prototype as well?

Tags: javascript

I am reading JavaScript The Good Parts without prior js knowledge and this bit baffled me. I think I need clarification.

> JavaScript allows the basic types of the language to be augmented. In Chapter 3, we saw that adding a method to Object.prototype makes that method available to all objects. This also works for functions, arrays, strings, numbers, regular expressions, and booleans.
>   For example, by augmenting Function.prototype, we can make a method available to all functions:

Then goes on with this example:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
     this.prototype[name] = func;
     return this;
};
```

Now every basic type has a "method" method so new functions can be defined for them, like:

```
Number.method('integer', function () {
    return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceiling' : 'floor'](this);
});
```

But the book previously noted everything links to Object not to Function! How is this working out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, only functions have `Function.prototype`. `Number` is a constructor *function* so it is "linked" to that prototype.

Here's what the nodejs/V8 shell says about `Number`:

```
> Number
[Function: Number]
> typeof Number
'function'
```

Comment: Not very intuitive but at least consistent. Thanks.